# Android Emulator EXIF Data

Tags: android, android-emulator, exif

I am currently working on small part of my graduation work. I have to test out, how you can get the location of the user without the location permission.
One way is that the user gets asked to take a picture and when the Camera application has the permission to get the location, you can read out the EXIF-Data from the picture which was taken by the user. 
I tested it out on multiple real devices (2x Android 9, 1x Android 6, 1x Android 7.1) and it works on these devices.
But if I use the emulator (The camera has the location permisson, location service is turned on, camera is tagging the location to the image) the Android EXIF interface can't read out any EXIF data.
 
If I take manually a photo with the Camera app and look at the details of the photo in the gallery, the location is saved.

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

EDIT:
The most important code:

```
        private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.readoutexifwithoutpermissions",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private void readOutImageData() {
        Log.i(TAG, currentPhotoPath);
        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(currentPhotoPath);
            File file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            Log.i(TAG, "size of file: " + file.length());
            Log.i(TAG, "reading out something..." + exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE));
            this.txtLatitude.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE));
            this.txtLongitude.setText(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );

        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

SOLUTION:
I don't know why, but when you are using the Camera via Intent no additional information gets stored. If you are installing another camera app like Open Camera, it is working. (Only happens in the emulator)

Comment: Please provide some examples with code, logs, images, etc.

Comment: I added the main functions :)

Answer (score 0):

The location is most certainly saved as meta info in the media store and not in exif header of jpg.

Download jpg to pc and inspect there exif to see.

You can query the media store for the location too. You dont need the location permission but need another special permission then. Well on Android Q.

I have an Android 8 device where the camera app already behaved that way.

Terrible to loose all info when you use the file somewhere else or make a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will try it out as soon as possible...

But why does it work on real devices like OnePlus 5T, Huawei P10, ...?

Comment: That depends on the Camera app used. The camera app decides where to write location info. In exif header or in media store. Try other apps from the store. Most will use exif for location. As said ... already on Android 8 i saw this behaviour.

Comment: I just exported an image and the location data is written to the EXIF header.
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I dont know what you are asking exactly now. 
Suggestions for what? Please repeat/rephrase.

Comment: Why it isn't working on the emulator. The emulator camera writes the location data to the EXIF header. So my app should be able to read it. 
But only on the virtual devices > API Level 23 I only receive null, with real devices it is working...

Comment: Okay I just found out that when you are using the camera via the Intent no additional information gets saved (meta data or exif). If you are just using the Camera app meta data and EXIF gets saved.

Comment: Meta data and exif? That is new for me.